# Installing tracegraph tool in Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan

Tags: software-installation, graphics

I am trying to install **tracegraph tool** on my device. I have been searching for a way to install this tool. However, unfortunately, I didn't found anything useful that compatible with my device because there are some packages that required to tracegraph installation is not found on my device, and I don't know if there any packages that could be used in **Ubuntu 19.10 Eaon** and help in tracegraph installation.

If anyone knows a way to install this tool in my device  **Ubuntu 19.10 Eaon**, I will be thoughtful for him/her.

Comment: Give us a source/URL for this tool.

Comment: Assume `tracegraph202`. The start command is `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./bin/glnx86 && ./trgraph` .... but unfortunately this tool will work only with a very old "Linux OS". https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/tracegraph-4175602766/#3

Comment: For example, this link provides a way to install tracegraph tool (http://ns-2.blogspot.com/2008/10/trace-graph-network-simulator-ns-2.html).

Comment: Is there any other tool that could be used to analyze energy instead of tracegraph?